# Using multiple boolean arrays for indexing and assigning

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, assign

I just came across the following issue I really do not understand:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
m = a < 5
n = a[m] < 2

print a[m][n]
# array([0, 1])
```

So far so good. Here comes the problem:

```
a[m][n] *= 10000
print a[m][n]
# array([0, 1])
```

I do not understand why the assignment a[m][n] *= 10000 is not working. I know for sure that it works if I use just one array for indexing:

```
a[m] *= 10000
print a[m]
# array([    0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000])
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command:

```
a[m] *= 1000
```

does an [in-place assignment](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays), whereas:

```
a[m][n] *= 1000
```

is first creating a new array `a[m]` and doing an in-place assignment for the new copy, and that's why the original array isn't modified.